# running multiple random post queries

Tags: wordpress

I am building a grip type slider for wordpress. each grid has 17 blocks pulling in 17 different posts posts. I have had to create 17 seperate queires as each block is a different size.

This was all working fine, but i have decided to make the posts in each block random on page load.

Here is my query:

```
$do_not_duplicate = array();
$featucat = get_option('themnific_slider1_category');
$my_query = new WP_Query( 'post_type=myportfoliotype&showposts=1&orderby=rand');     
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();$do_not_duplicate[] =  $post->ID;
```

My problem is the $do_not_duplicate function isnt working correctly, i still get duplicate posts.

Any ideas on what i am doing wrong?

Cheers, Dan

Comment: how would i make 1 query for 17 posts, when the divs that contain them are all different sizes? p.s that doesnt really help me.....

Comment: your answer was completely irrelevant and you down vote me? pathetic....

Comment: Well, you won't get a lot of answers if you speak like this with people who tries to help you... Bye.

Answer (score 2):

I don't really understand what you're after, but I once had a similiar problem. May-be [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53578/one-random-post-from-multiple-custom-post-types) is helpful.

Also a good tutorial about queries over [here](http://betterwp.net/9-latest-posts-from-each-post-type/).

Comment: basically i am querying multiple post type with multiple queries using $do_not_duplicate[], but i am still getting duplicates